# Center my Chart Using a Div Tag

Tags: html, css

I am using `align="center"`, but it does not work and it is the same left.

My code is below:

```
    <div align="center">
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">my text</a>
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">text</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">text</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">text</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">text</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

what `tag` should I use? I want the entire to chart go to the center.

this is output  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boQqrg

Comment: That is a lot of `li`s. Have you tried `.tree {display: block; margin: auto;}`?

Comment: Wich tag represents your chart? You should add more details of your chart representation in your question.

Comment: Can you create a JS fiddle or codepen of your code so we can help you better?

Comment: now my chart is left, i want it go center, this is just i want.

Comment: this is: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boQqrg   and i want be center just

Comment: @antonio https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzQMjK (remove `float` on `.tree li`, add `margin: auto` to `.tree ul`)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `margin: auto;` if that did not work.

Also note that one problem you may be having is that you were using `align="center"`. Using quotation marks will not work.

Comment: i think you not understad, now chart is left of page, i want it go center of page, understand?

Comment: this is: codepen.io/anon/pen/boQqrg and i want be center just

Answer (score 0):

I should remove `float` on `.tree li` and add `margin: auto` to `.tree ul`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center it horizontally and vertically, add this to your ul tag:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

But I'd suggest that you review your entire code. You're using floats without clearfixing (read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)) and it causes the height to collapse.